# Composer DAG triggers Dataflow job and runs succesfully, but the end file doesn't appear in output bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I have set up a DAG that runs a Dataflow job. Dag triggers it fine, and it runs successfully yet the output file doesn't appear in the output location. The output location is a bucket in another project and the SA being used has access to write to that bucket... any idea why the file is not generating?

DF Job:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.value_provider import StaticValueProvider
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from datetime import datetime
import logging


class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
        @classmethod
        def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
                parser.add_value_provider_argument('--templated_int', type=int)
                parser.add_value_provider_argument("--input", type=str )
                parser.add_value_provider_argument("--output", type=str )

class process_file(beam.DoFn):
        def __init__(self, templated_int):
                self.templated_int = templated_int

        def process(self, an_int):
                yield self.templated_int.get() + an_int

def clean_file():
        pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
        user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)
        tstmp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H")
        output = user_options.output 
        logging.info('Input: ', user_options.input)
        logging.info('Output: ', output)
                                
        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

                p | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(user_options.input, skip_header_lines=1) | 'Split into rows' >> beam.Map(lambda x:x.split(",")) | 'Confirm index locations' >> beam.Map(lambda x:f'{x[0]},{x[1]}{x[2]}{x[3]}{x[4]},{x[5]}') | 'Write to clean file' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output) 
        p.run().wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        clean_file()
```

[image: DF Job graph]

Answer (score 0):

When you select a step in your Dataflow Pipeline graph, the logs panel toggles from displaying Job Logs generated by Dataflow service showing logs from the Compute Engine instances running your pipeline step.

Cloud Logging combines all the collected logs from your projects’s Compute Engine instances in one location. Additionally, see [Logging pipeline messages](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#AddingLogging) for more information on using dataflow’s various logging capabilities.